# Open two cmd's simultaneously with run-dialog

Tags: windows, parameters, cmd

I'm currently trying to open two cmd's simultaneously with the windows run-dialog, but both having some commands thereself already aswell. What I mean is the following:

What I have now is: `cmd.exe /T:01 /K mode CON: COLS=15 LINES=1`, so open a CMD and tell it, that it should have the color 01 and that is has the specified size. What I want now is opening a second cmd at the same time, that has different colors and different amount of cols and lines.

I tried to simply set a second `/K`parameter with the command `start cmd`, but it's not working, where as the simple command `cmd.exe /K start cmd` is working....

Can anybody help me and tell me, how it's working to open 2 cmd's with different options on each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `&` to chain commands together (note that this is in `cmd`, not the run dialog - the second `cmd` is still launched through the first `cmd`):

```
cmd.exe /T:01 /K (mode CON: COLS=15 LINES=1) & (start cmd /K mode CON: COLS=30 LINES=20)
```

Comment: That works, thank you, didn't expect it to be that easy.. Do you also happen to know how to change the font size trough a command in cmd?

Comment: @user5638730 I don't think that's possible - the only interface is `mode`, which is really mostly for DOS compatibility. However, you could use shortcuts instead - those allow you to specify all the things you're trying to set easily. Just make two shortcuts for `cmd`, set whatever you need in properties, and run them from Run using the above approach.